# SNR requirements / standard for GFSK modulation

Tags: fsk, communication-standard

I'm trying to compute a basic spacecraft link budget, and could use some help with understanding/sourcing minimum SNR requirements for demod of GFSK encoded signals. I'm familiar with the [DVB-S2X standard](https://dvb.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/A171-2_DVB-S2X_Implementation-Guidelines_Draft-TR-102-376-2_v121_Apr-2020.pdf) and using the information in *"Table 1: Performance at Quasi Error Free FER=10-5 (AWGN Channel)"* to perform link budget calculations. For example:

```
Mode        Es/N0 (dB)    Spectral Efficiency (bps/Hz)
QPSK 2/9    -2.85         0.43
QPSK 13/45  -2.03         0.57
QPSK 9/20    0.22         0.89
```

I use this data to determine the minimum required Es/N0 (SNR) at the receive modem, and the resulting data rate given the spectral efficiency and carrier bandwidth. Does a similar standard exist for GFSK modulation? Something like:

```
Mode        Es/N0 (dB)    Spectral Efficiency (bps/Hz)
2-GFSK      xx.xx         y.yy
4-GFSK      xx.xx         y.yy
8-GFSK      xx.xx         y.yy
```

or is there an estimation equation I can use based on receiver sensitivity, NF, bandwidth, etc.? I've been searching around the web without success, which made me wonder if I conceptually misunderstood how GFSK works / should be used in a link budget.